# how to start developing using joomla?

Tags: php, joomla1.5

i installed joomla,apache server,php,mysql in my pc, after that how to start developing web apps using joomla.

Comment: Try [Good tutorials for Joomla?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850885/good-tutorials-for-joomla).

Comment: Just google for Jumla Tutorials. Don't make people to google for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tutorials to start with:

- [Hello World 1 - The first steps](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/775/125/)
- [Module Hello World 1](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/775/125/)
- [Joomla Tutorials](http://www.joomlatutorials.com/)
- [More Joomla Tutorial](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/)
- [Joomla! Official Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/)
- [Video Tutorials](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla-tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

Download the required extensions using [Joomla Extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/) gallery and add to your original joomla site.

You can grab lot of themes from the internet and if required customized them by editing CSS files and images.

This way will be a quicker coz coding from scratch